# alert after typing @ plus one more letter Jquery

Tags: jquery, indexof, keyup

I am creating a textarea to create posts, where if I type `@` plus one more letter, then it appears an alert () the one which will be replaced by an inline user search bar like twitter (I already have it).

```
  <textarea id=post></textarea>

       $(function() {
         $('#post').keyup(function() {
             if ( $(this).val().indexOf("@") > -1 ) {
                 alert("found");
              }
            });
      });
```

I'm using this function, it recognizes the `@` but if continue writing something else, the alert continues showing up. What I want is the alert appears after writing `@` and another letter to  make the inline search bar works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a Snippet for you.

This uses "count" to check if the amount of characters in the textarea changes. Because the "@" can be made using "AltGr+2" (2 keyups) or "Alt+64" (3 keyups). The code belows avoid problems with ASCII characters that can be formed that way.

Also, I checked from "lastChar" instead your indexOf("@"). This allows you to fire your tag function more than once in the same textarea.

Like "Hey @Jean, I'm @NiMusco and hope it helps you".

Sure it can be improved, but by way of example it's fine.

```js
var count = 0;
var tagging = false;
var users_example = ["jean", "nimusco"];

$('#post').keyup(function(){
  var text = $(this).val();
  
  if(text.length > count){
    var lastChar = text.substr(count);
    
    if(lastChar == "@"){
      tagging = true;
    }
    
    //White space break the tagging.
    if(lastChar == " "){
      tagging = false;
    }
    
    //Adapt this to your tagging function
    if(tagging == true){
      var username = text.substr(text.lastIndexOf('@') + 1, text.length);
      console.log(username);
      if($.inArray(username.toLowerCase(), users_example) !== -1){
        alert('found it!');
        tagging = false;
      }
    }
  }
  
  count = text.length;
});
```

```css
#post{
width:300px;
height:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="post">

</textarea>
```

Comment: Hey @NiMusco thank you for your answer. Yes your code helps a lot. I have this question, though,  what if the prompt shows up after typing a letter after the @ character, something like: @f and showsup the prompt. I was wondering if necessary to use any regex.

Comment: The promt will always shows up if a "@" is the last character. If you achieve to write "@f" realy fast, then no prompt will appears. (I tried myself on chrome, let me know if it's working different for you).

Comment: It works fine in my browser. What I was wondering is if the alert or prompt shows up after typing a letter after the @. @f or @q or @j

Comment: Just edited my answer with progressive tagging example. Try with "Jean" and "Nimusco"

Comment: It was what I was looking for, I mixed it with my inline searching code and works perfectly, thank you !!

Comment: by tha way, after the list of results shows up, what should I do to autocomplete or replace  a single result, for example `@NiMusco` after typing ... `@NiMu`, let me know to update my answer with my whole code. thank you.

Comment: Ok. thank you. this is the link https://stackoverflow.com/q/48977187/9369685  As I said, my only problem would be to replace the value in one of the users suggestions with the text within the textarea