# Autocomplete textarea text after click result on list jquery

Tags: jquery, append, attr, keyup

I'm making a textarea for users to create posts. In those posts they have the possibility to tag someone `@myfriend`. I successfully with @NiMusco help, developed the jquery code, but what I'm getting into trouble at the moment of autocompleting after clicking one of the results, for example  replace `@Jean` (listed result) by `@Je` written within the textarea.

```
  <textarea id=inline_search></textarea>
   <div >
       <ul id=show_inline_users>
       </ul>
  </div>
```

The php outputs json data, this type

```
$arr[] = array("channel" => $obj->channel,...); 

/* Return JSON */
echo json_encode($arr);
```

the Jquery is correct, but I just cant autocomplete the user name

```
var count = 0;
var tagging = false;

$('#inline_search').keyup(function(){
    var text = $(this).val();

    if(text.length > count){
        var lastChar = text.substr(count);

       if(lastChar == "@"){
          tagging = true;
       }

      //White space break the tagging.
      if(lastChar == " "){
       tagging = false;
       }

    //Adapt this to your tagging function
     if(tagging == true){
       var username = text.substr(text.lastIndexOf('@') + 1, text.length);

   ////////////INLINE SEARCH INI///////////////////////////////////////
   var searchKeyword = username;
       if(searchKeyword.length>0){ 
      $.post('search/users.php', { keywords: searchKeyword }, 
    function(data) {
      $('#show_inline_users').empty();
     $.each(data, function() {

$('#show_inline_users').append("<li class=opt title='"+this.channel+"' >"+this.channel+"</li>");

        /*$('.opt').click(function(){ 
         var user_title = $(this).attr("title");
          alert(user_title);


          $('#inline_search').val($('#inline_search').val()+ " @"+user_title);
         });*/



        });
        },"json").fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //any errors?
                alert(thrownError); //alert with HTTP error 
            }); 
     }else{$('#show_inline_users').empty();}

   ///////////////INLINE SEARCH END//////////////////////////////////////  

     }
   }

   count = text.length;
  });
```

I have problem on those lines, I thought to use `.attr()` to replace

```
 $('#show_inline_users').append("<li class=opt title='"+this.channel+"' >"+this.channel+"</li>");

       /*$('.opt').click(function(){ 
     var user_title = $(this).attr("title");
      alert(user_title);

      $('#inline_search').val($('#inline_search').val()+ " @"+user_title);
     });*/


     });*/
```

For example if I type `Hi my username on stackoverflow is @Je` within the textarea, there appear a list of users suggestions

```
 <ul id=show_inline_users>
      <li class=opt title='Jenna'>Jenna</li>
        <li class=opt title='Jeremy'>Jeremy</li>
           <li class=opt title='Jean'>Jean</li>
                <li class=opt title='Jelly'>Jelly</li>
     </ul>
```

If I click on Jean Option, the title value replaces the user text within the textarea like in twitter or faceb0ok.

Comment: where is the jquery code that changes the value of the textarea ?

Comment: it would be something like that..`$('#inline_search').val($('#inline_search').val()+ " @"+user_title);` but thi one is too basic

Comment: can you attach screenshot or atleast a jsfiddle to showcase your issue.

Comment: something like this --> https://yuku-t.com/textcomplete/ ?

Comment: yes. this is just a autocomplet like that. I'm reading somethig about `Caret` or cursor position, concepts that could be key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, sorry for the delay. Remember that the tag menu only appears after a @. And we have the last position of "@" here: text.lastIndexOf('@').

Something like this (but adapted to what you have).
Try clicking different names.

```js
var text = $('#post').val();
var at_pos = text.lastIndexOf('@');

$('.opt').click(function(){
    var username = $(this).attr("title");
    text = text.substring(0, at_pos);
    text = text + username;
    $('#post').val(text);
});
```

```css
#post{
width:300px;
height:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="post">
   Im gonna tag @Je
</textarea>

<ul id=show_inline_users>
  <li class=opt title='Jenna'>Jenna</li>
  <li class=opt title='Jeremy'>Jeremy</li>
  <li class=opt title='Jean'>Jean</li>
  <li class=opt title='Jelly'>Jelly</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hey!, This definitely made my day thank you very much, well, I was testing the code and is pretty good. there is this minor thing I realised that for example if I write `Hi hello my username is @Je[an]` it works perfectly, but in case I want to edit and add  between  `hello` and `my` the next: `you @NiMu` the code doesnt work to autocomplete `@NiMu` to `NiMusco` do you have any close solution for that?

Comment: Good point. Since the code searches for the last @ it's not possible. Read about prop("selectionStart"). It returns the current position of the pointer in the textarea. Based on current position, check if -1 is an @. Then, the same as above. Let me know if you need help.